# Android: using custom font as fallback font for missing glyph

Tags: android

is there anyway to set custom font as a fallback font to the default font?

I need to display some cjk characters not supported by android's default font (which I think is noto font for non latin characters). I have a custom font consists of the glyphs missing, so I'm thinking to use noto as the main font, and set my custom font as fallback.

The only way I can come up with is to make noto font as a typeface and set my custom font as fallback. Then I can assign this typeface to where I need it.
However, this mean I need to programmatically assign almost all textview in the app, which doesn't seem right... (and elegant)

I would like to ask what is the best practice for this scenario? Like, perhaps there's a way to declare them as a font family in XML?

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer myself :)

After trying, I think the easiest way is to merge two font files together.

Just make sure the font's license allows you to do so.